# Add custom object to the script

Tags: c#, json, object, unity-game-engine

I just cant manage to add a public object to the dcript i have.
There is code:

```
public class Player : MonoBehaviour {

public string charName  = "";
public int currentLevel = 0;
public int experiense   = 0;
public int strength     = 1;
public int agility      = 1;
public int maxHealth    = 30;
public float currentHealth = 30;
public int maxActionPoints = 5;
public int currentLevelPoints = 10;}
```

there is another script where i want to add a public property with this class

```
public class CharManager : MonoBehaviour {

public GameObject currentCharacter;
public GameObject charMenu;
public Player currentPlayerStats;

public void changeCharacter(GameObject character)
{
    if (currentCharacter){
        saveCharacter ();
    }

    currentCharacter = character;
    loadSavedInfo ();

}

void loadSavedInfo()
{

    string playerJson = "";
    if (currentCharacter.tag== "Man")
    {

        if (File.Exists(Application.persistentDataPath +"/Char1.json"))
        {
            playerJson = File.ReadAllText(Application.persistentDataPath +"/Char1.json");
        }

    }
    else
    {
        if (File.Exists(Application.persistentDataPath +"/Char2.json"))
        {
            playerJson = File.ReadAllText(Application.persistentDataPath +"/Char2.json");
        }
    }


    if (playerJson != string.Empty)
    {
        Player thePlayer = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Player>(playerJson);

        currentPlayerStats = thePlayer;

    }
    else
    {
        currentPlayerStats = gameObject.AddComponent<Player>() as Player;
    }
}
```

This code add NEW player component and currentPlayerStats have class CharManager... what am i doing wrong?
Any help is very appreciated!

Comment: From the code you copied here, it seems the Player class should not be a MonoBehaviour..? It only holds stat values, maybe try to make it not a MonoBehaviour ?

Comment: i did try to do that. so how could i get this property from another script? GetComponent does not work.

Answer (score 1):

gameObject.AddComponent() adds a MonoBehaviour derived component to the game object. Player does not derive from MonoBehaviour thus it cannot be added

Looks like Player is just a regular class, so you can just create an object of that class

```
Player currentPlayerStats = new Player();
```

Comment: public class Player : **MonoBehaviour**. So it is derive MonoBehaviour.

Comment: I can't believe I didn't see that, I triple checked, I'm so sorry.

But now I can't see what's the problem.

Comment: No problem at all. i did solve it. Thanks for response!

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out.
Player class must be non MonoBehaviour class. A class where i have to access the player class should have a public property:

```
public Player thePlayer;
```

not

```
public GameObject thePlayer;
```

Thanks everyone!